# CosmosDb, selecting all documents where any property value matches criteria

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

In my case document structure varies and is complex, and I'd like to find all documents where any property value matches my criteria.
How do I do it with linq or select query?

```
var value = "value";
var db = await CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync("....",
new (string databaseId, string containerId)[] { ("...", "...")} );

var data = 
  db.GetContainer("...","...")
  .GetItemLinqQueryable<Dictionary<string, object>>(true)
  .Where(x=>x.ContainsValue(value)) // THIS DOES NOT WORK - not supported exception.
  .ToList(); // THIS IS TEMPORARY
```

Using ContainsValue throws following exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Method 'ContainsValue' is not supported., Windows/10.0.18363 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.21.1
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ArrayBuiltinFunctions.Visit(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.BuiltinFunctionVisitor.VisitBuiltinFunctionCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitNonSubqueryScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitNonSubqueryScalarExpression(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression expression, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(LambdaExpression lambda, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitWhere(ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression, IDictionary`2 parameters, CosmosLinqSerializerOptions linqSerializerOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.SqlTranslator.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression, CosmosLinqSerializerOptions linqSerializerOptions, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.HandleMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, IDictionary`2 parameters, CosmosLinqSerializerOptions linqSerializerOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.Evaluate(Expression expression, CosmosLinqSerializerOptions linqSerializerOptions, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.CosmosLinqQuery`1.CreateFeedIterator(Boolean isContinuationExpected)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.CosmosLinqQuery`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at PALManagerBlazor.Data.RepoSearchService.Search(String value) in C:\Git\PAL\PALManagerBlazor\PALManagerBlazor\Data\WeatherForecastService.cs:line 38
   at PALManagerBlazor.Pages.Search.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Git\PAL\PALManagerBlazor\PALManagerBlazor\Pages\Search.razor:line 35
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

How do I query all documents which have any property with some chosen value?

Comment: What is the question? Expected output vs input?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary How do I query all documents which have any property with some chosen value?

Comment: You’ve said “THIS DOES NOT WORK” - what output does it give?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary not supported exception.

Comment: Please add the full exception to the question

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary done.

Comment: Finally, can you post the output of `var data = db.GetContainer("...","...").GetItemLinqQueryable<Dictionary<string, object>>(true)` before doing the .Where query?

Comment: Seems like the error is fairly clear, that `.containsValue()` isn't supported. What, exactly, are you attempting to do: check for a property's value, or check for the existence of a property? Please edit your question to be clear (and please don't put this clarification in comments - edit your question).

Answer (score 2):

### Word of advice: Don't do this

Finding documents which contain a chosen value is not indexable. Meaning even if you made such a query it will be a full scan. That is, unbearably costly. Don't go there, it'll just bite you hard down the line. **You should think about redesigning your data model instead**.

Even if you don't care about performance and cost, **AFAIK there is no out-of-box syntax for "search everywhere" in CosmosDB**.

If you do insist you want this happen, then I see these paths forward:

### Process in client

That is `.ToList()` earlier, download all the documents and let LINQ work on C# model. This way you work around the `NotSupportedException`.

The RU/bandwidth usage will be crazy though. Unless you have a really small no-growth dataset, then this is most likely a bad choice to make, unless you need it just once and don't want to invest in anything better.

### Process in server with UDF

If OOB SQL API does not support this then you can do everything with JS objects. Just execute this "search everywhere" as [User-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-udfs).

RU consumption will still be crazy as it will not utilize any index, but you wouldn't have to download everything.
On another downside, you would mix logic into data layer and troubleshooting UDFs is a pain.

### Create indexable field in doc

If you control all document creates/updates,  you could duplicate all "searchable" values into a separate property as an array, a la:

```
{
    "one": "data1",
    "anohter": 3,
    ... 
    "searchValues": ["data1", 3, ... ]
}
```

This `searchValues`could be indexed and queries would be simple and fast:

```
select * from c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.SearchValues, @myValue)
```

The downside is that you'd have ensure this index field is always in sync. You could use [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#triggers) as well to help you here.

Document size also grows considerably, but you don't have to query the duplicated bits to client and storage is cheap.

You could also store this index field in a separate document and maybe use Change feed to keep index documents updated. You can do a lot of tricks around this..

### Index outside of CosmosDB

This would incur extra complexity in tech stack and extra cost, but you could do a lot of advanced search tricks this way. Most likely also "search everywhere" fast.

For example, see [Azure Cosmos DB - integration with Azure Search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyoYu1Wzk4w). I think you could also integrate with ElasticSearch, etc.

.. or just build your own external index.